# Android double not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, double

I'm having this strange issue with android studio when i print a double value such as 1/4 like :

```
double test = 1/4
System.out.println(test);

//the output is 0.0
```

When i am calculating score which is ((correct_ans/MAXIMUM_CHANCE)*RANGE) it also calculates answer as 0.0, where correct_ans, MAXIMUM_CHANCE and RANGE are all integers. This is then shown on my Text View using ""+score. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: have you tried something like 1.0/4.0 ? it might be doing the double conversion after doing integer division

Comment: @SamM is correct. 1/4 is integer division which results in 0 and then converted to double (0.0). Change one of the numbers to be a double and you will be fine

Comment: is casting double the only solution but thanks that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 / 2 = 2

4 / 3 = 1

3 / 3 = 1

2 / 4 = 0

int value / int value = int value

so : 1 / 4 = 0

because 1/4 = (int) 0.25  = 0

You can solve this by :

double value / int value = double value

1.0 / 4

OR

1 / 4.0

OR

1.0 / 4.0

Answer (score 1):

As per java rule the divider must be double/float, so try -

```
double test = 1/4.0;
System.out.println(test);
```

Answer will be

```
0.25
```